# Symfony2 - Session storage not working

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, fosuserbundle

I developed a symfony2 application with FOSUserBundle and the HWIoauthBundle for handling the user login and registrations. Everything works fine on the localhost environment.

On the production server the cache and logs folders are writable, cache is cleared - also used the warmup command -, assets are installed.

The application also seems to work, I see content from the database and can insert data where no user login is required.

Trying to login with a known user/pass simply returns to the same login page, no error or whatsoever. Register a new user returns the error that the csfr token is invalid. The CSFR token is available as hidden field in the form.

I searched the last few hours on the web to find any similar errors but none with a useful answer.

The production server is a linux machine running parallels with a Nginx proxy.

If you need to see any configuration please ask me so I can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Reasoning more to the essential of the errors, no response on login, incorrect tokens..
Looks like a session problem.

It turns out that the fallback to the session storage configuration in php.ini is not fail-proof. 
So I added the code below to config.yml:

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

Then, added the folder "sessions" and cleared the cache of the prod env.
Now it works like it should.

Hope this may help some others!

Answer (score 0):

This may be an edge case, but I lost session storage when a colleague changed 'session_prefix' to a value that had a space in it.

```
session_prefix: 'This will break'
```